# Django views show same content. Where are django views controlled?

Tags: python, django

I have a django application with two views that display the same content, but they shouldn't. I created the second by duplicating the code from the first and cannot figure out how to unhook these from each other. I am pretty sure the problem is in the `views.py` file of my app.

I have two views, 'journals-by-discipline' and 'journals-by-discipline-elsevier'

Here is the `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [

    # Journals by Discipline
    path('journals-by-discipline/', views.journals_by_discipline, name='journalsByDiscipline'),
    path('journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data),
    path('journals-by-discipline/journals-and-disciplines-map/', views.get_journals_and_disciplines_map),
    path('journals-by-discipline/disciplines-list/', views.disciplines_list), 

    # Journals By Discipline (Elsevier)
    path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/', views.journals_by_discipline_elsevier, name='journalsByDisciplineElsevier'),
    path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier),
    path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/journals-and-disciplines-map/', views.get_journals_and_disciplines_map),
    path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/disciplines-list/', views.disciplines_list), 

]
```

Here is the `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import datetime as datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from urllib.parse import unquote
import json
from .onefigr_analysis import Data

# Instantiate Data object to fetch data across all views
data = Data()



# Journals by Discipline Page

def journals_by_discipline(request):
    template_name = 'app/journals-by-discipline.html'
    return render(request, template_name)

@api_view(['GET'])
def journals_by_discipline_chart_data(request, discipline):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_discipline = unquote(discipline)
        return Response(data.journals_by_discipline_chart_data(discipline))

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_journals_and_disciplines_map(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.journals_and_disciplines_map()) 

@api_view(['GET'])
def disciplines_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.get_disciplines_list())




# Journals by Discipline - Elsevier page

def journals_by_discipline_elsevier(request):
    template_name = 'app/journals-by-discipline-elsevier.html'
    return render(request, template_name)   

@api_view(['GET'])
def journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier(request, discipline):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_discipline = unquote(discipline)
        return Response(data.journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier(discipline))
```

When running my app locally, I go to the journals-by-discipline page, I see the following response in my terminal:
[image]

This works as it should, it shows each URL in the `urls.py` page.

When I go to the journals-by-discipline-elsevier page, I see the following in the terminal:
[image]

This does not work as it should. I see the first url returned is correct: `/app/journals-by-discipline-elsevier/`, but then the second is the same as the previous page, which is incorrect: `/app/journals-by-discipline/disciplines-list/`

It should go to: `/app/journals-by-discipline-elsevier/disciplines-list/`
The following URLs should change accordingly

Why?? Where is this controlled in the application? I am not that familiar with the django framework and realize this may be specific to my app structure. But is there a generic place to control this?

Comment: *Why* are four requests being made in each of your examples?  I don't see any sort of redirect in the code you posted, so I guess it's something in the actual HTML that's loading those additional pages - and that's something you didn't show us.  Perhaps the Elsevier version of the root page wasn't edited to change the URLs it loads?

Comment: maybe the templates `journals-by-discipline-elsevier.html` and `journals-by-discipline.html` are the same?